# Cannot proceed on the switch case C programming

Tags: c, switch-statement, midi

I'm trying to parse MIDI file and send MIDI signal. I'm testing it first by print it on the screen. Right now, I'm stuck at parsing on the meta event (something that not sent as MIDI signal).

The result are showing that the first use of case already right but I can't processing on the second switch. To be precise, I can not processing on the FF byte after the first FF byte.

Here is my code:

```
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// Programmer      :   Grahmada Ruci Batara
/// File Name       :   midiread.c
/// Last modified   :   8 Mei 2014
/// Program Description :
///
///             Read MIDI file and return it as a MIDI output /
///             Membaca file MIDI dan mengembalikannya
///             sebagai MIDI keluaran
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/stat.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     DECLARATION / DEKLARASI
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define BAUDRATE B31250
#define MIDIDEVICE "/dev/ttyO4" //Beaglebone Black serial port
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

FILE* in_file;
char MIDIName[100]=" "; //Storing File Name
int MIDISize;
unsigned char buffer[999999]; // a copy of file for modified
char MThd[4] = "MThd";
unsigned char MTrk[4] = "MTrk";
int MTrksize1;
int i;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     FUNCTIONS / FUNGSI - FUNGSI
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// Getting file size / mencari ukuran file (fsize) ///
int fsize(FILE *fp){
    int prev=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
    int sz=ftell(fp); // get current file pointer
    fseek(fp,prev,SEEK_SET); //go back to where we were
    return sz;
}

//send MIDI message
//void SendMIDImessage(unsigned char command, unsigned char MIDInote, unsigned char MIDIvelocity) {
  //Serial.write(command);//send note on or note off command 
  //Serial.write(MIDInote);//send pitch data
  //Serial.write(MIDIvelocity);//send velocity data
//}

//send MIDI message 1 byte
//void SendMIDImessage2(unsigned char command, unsigned char MIDInote) {
  //Serial.write(command);//send note on or note off command 
  //Serial.write(MIDInote);//send pitch data
//}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// --------------------------------     MAIN / UTAMA    --------------------------------------------
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
printf("Please Enter MIDI file with the extension (ex : file.mid): \n");
scanf("%s",&MIDIName); // Getting MIDI Name

in_file = fopen(MIDIName, "r"); // read only

if (! in_file ) // file checking
        {  
        printf("File not found!\n"); 
        exit(-1); 
        }

MIDISize = fsize(in_file); // Getting MIDI size

printf("file size : %d \n", MIDISize);

unsigned char temp;

for(i=0; i<MIDISize+1 ; i++) // copying the file to buffer
{
    fscanf( in_file, "%c", &temp );
    buffer[i]=temp;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     SERIAL COMMUNICATION / KOMUNIKASI SERIAL
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//fd = open(MIDIDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
//if(fd == -1) {
  //printf( "failed to open port\n" );
//}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     MThd (MIDI HEADER) PART
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] != MThd[i])
    {
    printf("NOT MIDI FILE!!!");
    return -1;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     MTrk (MIDI TRACK) 1 PART
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for(i=14; i<18; i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] != MTrk[(i-14)])
    {
    printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
    printf("MTrk NOT FOUND!!!");
    return -1;
    }
}

int temptot1;
int shiftk1=3;
int tot1 = 0;

for(i=18; i<22; i++)
{
    temptot1 = buffer[i];
    temptot1 += (temptot1 * (shiftk1*24));
    tot1 += temptot1;
    shiftk1--;
}

MTrksize1 = tot1;

printf ("MTrk following byte size : %x \n", MTrksize1);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///     MTrk (MIDI TRACK) 1 PART
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for(i=23; i< 23+MTrksize1; i++)
{
        if (buffer[i] > 0x7F)
        {
            switch (buffer[i])
            {
            case 0x80:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1], buffer[i+2]));      // note off (2 more bytes)
                            i += 2;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0x90:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1], buffer[i+2]));      // note on (2 more bytes)
                            i += 2;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xA0: 
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1], buffer[i+2]));      // aftertouch (2 more bytes)
                            i += 2;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xB0:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1], buffer[i+2]));      // cont. controller (2 more bytes)
                            i += 2;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xE0:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1], buffer[i+2]));      // pitch wheel (2 more bytes)
                            i += 2;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xC0:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1]));    // patch change (1 more byte)
                            i += 1;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xD0:
                            {
                            printf("%02x,  %02x",(buffer[i], buffer[i+1]));    // channel pressure (1 more byte)
                            i += 1;
                            break;
                            }
            case 0xFF:
            {
            switch (buffer[i+1]) 
                { //meta event
                    case 0x2F:
                        {
                            printf("END OF TRACK");
                            break;
                        };
                    default:
                        {
                        printf("i = %d \n", i);
                        printf("buffer[i] = %02x \n", buffer[i]);
                        i += 4 + buffer[i+2];
                        printf("i = %d \n", i);
                        printf("buffer[i] = %02x \n", buffer[i]);
                        break;
                        }
                };
            break;  
            }
            default: 
                    {
                    printf("i = %d \n", i);
                    printf("byte : %02x \n", buffer[i]);
                    printf("ERROR IN READING FILE 1");
                    return -1;
                    break;
                    }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        printf("i = %d \n", i);
        printf("byte : %02x \n", buffer[i]);
        printf("ERROR IN READING FILE 2");
        return -1;
        }
}


// tester
//for(i=0; i<MIDISize ; i++)
//{
    //printf("%02x  ",buffer[i]);
//}

fclose(in_file);
return 0; //end of program
}
```

I am going to implement it on the beaglebone black. Give me a suggestion if there is something that I need to know.

Comment: Why don't you post a minimal complete example instead?

Comment: You should make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: thks for the tips. cheers :)

Comment: i dont have any debugger for C. can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the length of the meta event correctly.

A meta event has the form FF *type* *length* *data…*, so the number of bytes you must skip (in addition to the FF byte itself) is, in most cases, 2 plus the length, not 4+length.

Also, the meta event length is a variable-length number, not a byte.

Also, I see no code for handling the delta time in front of each event.

Also, you are not handling running status.

---

I suggest you read and try to understand some existing SMF parser that is known to work.
See, for example, the functions `read_smf` and `read_track` in [aplaymidi.c](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=seq/aplaymidi/aplaymidi.c;hb=HEAD).

Comment: thanks, i will try to learn from the example that you give. but, actually i only forward those message. should i keep handling  the delta time and running status?

Comment: The program will not work at all without these features.